# Ubuntu Touch - Telegram new message count not reset after message has been read

Tags: ubuntu-touch, telegram

I have performed the Telegram update this morning. All went OK. However, I have noticed that I have an increasing total of notifications (on the Unity bar), that does not go when I read / reply to the messages. It appears to be keeping a total of all the messages I have received today, rather than showing me how may new/unread messages I have.

Has anyone else noticed this and is there a fix for it?

Comment: I have also noticed that when I receive / view a message on my pc, my phone continues to say I have a new message. Even though I have already opened it on the pc. 

Is this a setting issue again, that I need to configure as the two systems should be able to work together in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old known [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/telegram-app/+bug/1518616). One workaround is to launch the telegram app from the the left unity sliding bar (where you see open and/or pinned apps) or the apps scope instead of the notification menu at the top.

Comment: The sliding one worked. Hopefully, there will be a fix for this little issue soon, as most users would class this as basic phone requirements.